# Why this javac: File Not Found error?

Tags: java, linux, command-line, centos, javac

Working with some basic java apps on CentOS 5 linux and I have my `classpath` set to point to `home/pathToJava/bin` which contains `javac` and `java`

and I have `.java` files in `home/pathToFolderA/src`

and `home/pathToFolderB/gen-java`

When I run `javac` and `java` in `home/pathToFolderA/src` everything works perfectly

But when I run `javac` from within `home/pathToFolderB/gen-java` on `fileName.java` I get a file not found error, specifically

```
javac: file Not found: fileName.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Why could this be happening?

Thanks for all help

Comment: How are you running it in the second directory - does it exist there / do you have read permissions etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't set your **classpath** to point to your JDK bin directory -- instead it should be the **PATH** environment variable, which serves a different purpose to classpath. (The classpath defines a list of jars and directories containing compiled Java .class code; the PATH variable defines a list of paths where the shell needs to look and locate programs to execute when they are not found in the current directory -- so if you type for instance `zip` -- it would look in all the directories defined in `PATH` and figure out that `zip` program is located under `/usr/bin`)
Secondly if you want to compile sources from both directory you need to specify:

- all the paths where the sources are (both `home/pathToFolderA/src` and `home/pathToFolderB/gen-java`)
- the path where the compiled .class files to be generated
- specify in the classpath any library you might use in your source files

To sum it up, it would be something like this to compile:

```
javac -d /home/pathToFolderWithResultsOfCompilation -classpath /path/to/some.jar:/path/to/another.jar home/pathToFolderA/src/*.java home/pathToFolderB/gen-java/*.java
```

and to run your compiled programs:

```
java -classpath /path/to/some.jar:/path/to/another.jar:/home/pathToFolderWithResultsOfCompilation full.name.of.your.Java
```

Answer (score 6):

The classpath is used to find *class* files, not *source* files. (Nor is it used to find the `java` and `javac` binaries; those are found in your normal path.) You need to specify the files to compile explicitly:

```
javac /home/pathToFolderA/src/fileName.java
```

Obviously if you're already *in* `/home/pathToFolderA/src` then you can just use `fileName.java` because that's treated as being relative to your current directory.

Comment: mmm dont know .... If I am in pathToFolderA/src and I call javac fileName.java ..it should work...and it does. It is when I am in the other folder that it doesn't work...the question is why?

Comment: @algorithmicCoder: Because in the other folder, `fileName.java` doesn't exist. Try `cat fileName.java` and I dare say that won't find the file either. **The classpath isn't used to find source files.**

Comment: you were absolutely right..`fileName.java` was in one sub-directory lower....absolutely dumb mistake..I'd look at Liv's answer for how to correctly specify my paths and classpaths...thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Working with some basic java apps on CentOS 5 linux and I have my `classpath` set to point to `home/pathToJava/bin` which contains `javac` and `java`

That's wrong. The classpath is used to find `*.class` files, not operating system specific executables. The `bin` directory of your JDK does not belong in the classpath. Note that the classpath is also not for finding `*.java` source files.

When you run `javac` you need to specify the path to the source file, if it isn't in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your file name contain no spaces

Eg:

```
HelloWorld.java
```

usually the errors occur when you rename the file by copy past that will cause a space between the name and the dot (this is the mistake:`HelloWorld .java`).

and make sure you changed the directory to the same folder your file in

Comment: I couldn't believe all this struggle was due to the filename. I just renamed and boom ! my program got compiled. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without a listing of the directory "gen-java" and the exact command you're typing,my guess would be that you're trying to compile a file that doesn't exist. Linux is case sensitive, so maybe that's your problem. Or the file doesn't exist.