# Java - not-a-file-error

Tags: java, javac

I'm trying to compile a java file. It's called "Main.java".
When I use `javac Main.java` I get the following error:

```
javac: not a file: Main.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

I did find alot of other people getting a `file not found` but never a not a file.
Using the latest jdk from oracle (freshly downloaded) under Windows 10.

Comment: I assume that `dir` or `ls` confirms the file is where you think it is?

Comment: dir says, there is a Main.java, yes :)

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a space or other unexpected character in the file name?

Comment: I get that exact error message if `Main.java` is a *directory* rather than a file. Could you check that it really is a file? What happens if you run `type Main.java`?

Comment: Yes. To test it, I renamed it. Still the same.

Comment: The usual error message when the file doesn't exist is `javac: file not found: Main.java`. This indicates that while `Main.java` does exist, it is not a readable file.  Maybe it's a directory? Something else is happening, but based on what you provided we can't tell.

Comment: type returns the code inside the file

Comment: Run the command `dir /n` and look at the entry for `Main.java`.  Does it contain the string `<DIR>`?

Comment: Please show the contents of your `Main.java`. Especially the line starting with `package`.

Comment: Maybe this post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108598/why-this-javac-file-not-found-error. :)

Comment: I reduced it down to this for now:
public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args){
 }
}

Comment: Are you able to compile any *other* Java files? Does this happen in all directories? (Just wondering if it's a permissions issue.)

Comment: Seems to happen to any java-file. Tried one from a few years ago. Same error.

Comment: @blafasel The content of the file is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if your java file is inside a folder that is been synced by OneDrive.

Try to place your file in a different folder that is not been synced by OneDrive and it will work.